# Can I dynamically inject a module into another module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assume I have 2 modules in two separate files:

The first is for everyone, call it myApp:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['dependency.one', 'dependency.one']);
```

In another file: `admin.js` I have another module which manages the administrative functions.

```
var myAdmin = angular.module('myAdmin', ['dependency.three', 'dependency.four']);
```

Only logged in admin users are served with admin.js.

Is it possible to inject the myAdmin module into the myApp module from within the `admin.js` file? Alternately, is there some way to include all the myAdmin stuff, but only if the admin.js file is linked in the page header, or some alternative solution I am not seeing? $inject does not appear to work in this context.

Comment: what about var injector = angular.injector(['myModule', 'ng']); see documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: That would be an interesting solution. I don't think that this would inject the whole admin module into the application though.

Comment: @Lorenzo this would simply create a new injector / application with a provided set of modules. It would _not_ add modules to the existing application.

Comment: Ok I get it! thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, not in the current (1.x) version of AngularJS. When an application starts it needs to be provided the full set of modules to be used within an application. So, you would have re-bootstrap the whole application to take additional modules into account.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame. Is there a recommended solution to the issue of not wanting to ship out admin JavaScript to non-admin users?

Comment: Note that I am including both JavaScript files before the app is bootstrapped.

Comment: You could simply create 2 SPAs - one for admins and another one for regular users. Things should improve a lot in AngularJS 2.0.

Comment: I could do, and have a separate admin system. My goal is to have the edit form slide down from the top of the page when an edit link is clicked. It would be easy if I just included all the Javascript in a single module, but it feels wrong to ship out a bunch of JavaScript to a user who will never use it. There must be a way to inject additional dependencies into a module.

Comment: Aha, there is the required attribute of the module, see here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#requires

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this myself for the benefit of future searchers.

The .required attribute of a module holds the dependencies. You can require additional modules by pushing to this attribute.

In this admin.js file, I could simply write:

```
var myAdmin = angular.module('myAdmin', ['dependency.three', 'dependency.four']);
myApp.requires.push('myAdmin');
```

And myApp will now receive myAdmin.

Modules must be configured before they are bootstrapped, so you cannot insert additional dependencies at run time. They must be included before the app is bootstrapped.